# GCC from source - possible issues with system default GCC one?

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker, shared-libraries, loader

I am thinking to download the GCC source code (latest version), compile it and develop all my applications with it.

Now, my doubts are related to what would happen if I need to interact with other libraries.

E.g. suppose you are using GCC 9 and you need to use external libraries installed in your Linux OS that have been build with GCC 5 (or older). Would there be any problem at runtime?

What other problems could you expect to experience using a compiler that is different from the system default one?

What are the relationships between the new compiler runtime and the runtime of the system default one?